# SQL syntax error while trying to retrieve primary key

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I am trying to update a table with a JSON call.

```
@Override
public List<GroupsDetails> editGroupList(String Name, String startDate, String endDate, Integer Status_GroupID, Integer GroupsID) {
  SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibernateSessionManager.getSessionFactory();
  Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();
  try{
    transaction.begin();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<GroupsDetails> groupList=session.createQuery("UPDATE GroupsDetails SET Name='" + Name + "', StartDate='" + startDate + "', EndDate='" + endDate + "', Status_GroupID=" + Status_GroupID + " WHERE GroupsID=" + GroupsID).list();
    System.out.println(startDate);
    return groupList;
  }finally{
    session.close();
  }
   }
```

But I keep getting an error which says that does not support DML operations.
The error is :

```
    Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE com.nebuilder.ats.pojo.GroupsDetails SET Name='Alpha', StartDate='21-06-2014', EndDate='23-08-2014', Status_GroupID=1 WHERE GroupsID=1]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE com.nebuilder.ats.pojo.GroupsDetails SET Name='Alpha', StartDate='21-06-2014', EndDate='23-08-2014', Status_GroupID=1 WHERE GroupsID=1]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

When Im trying createSQLQuery

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Comment: I don't know hibernate but `createQuery()` seems to be the wrong choice for running an update (and the error message also says that).

Comment: createSQLQuery() makes even bigger errors.

Comment: Why do you use hibernate at all if you are not interested in O/R mapping?

Comment: Any method with `query` it the name seems like a bad choice. you are not running a "query", you are running an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [query.executeUpdate()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#executeUpdate%28%29):

```
public int executeUpdate()
                  throws HibernateException
```

> ```
> Execute the update or delete statement.
>
> The semantics are compliant with the ejb3 Query.executeUpdate() method.
>
> Returns:
>     The number of entities updated or deleted.
> ```

So your code should be something like this:

```
try{
    transaction.begin();
    int count = session.createQuery("UPDATE GroupsDetails SET Name='" + Name + "', StartDate='" + startDate + "', EndDate='" + endDate + "', Status_GroupID=" + Status_GroupID + " WHERE GroupsID=" + GroupsID).executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Number of records updated = " + count);
    transaction.comit();
  } catch(Exception ex){
    transaction.rollback();
    ex.printStacktrace();
}finally{
    session.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method list() is not supported for DML operations, you'll have to use executeUpdate() in this case; which will return the number of rows updated.
Also you will have to call transaction. commit() to persist the update.